# SqlAlchemy: Get instances of certain type in a relationship that can contain objects of several types

Tags: python, oop, class, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have an application with a "BaseVisibilizer"  class that is base
class for two other classes:

```
class BaseVisibilizer(declarativeBase):
       __tablename__ = "base_visibilizers"
       _polymorphicIdentity = Column("polymorphic_identity", String(20), key="polymorphicIdentity")
       __mapper_args__ = {
               'polymorphic_on': _polymorphicIdentity,
               'polymorphic_identity': None
       }

       def __init__(self):
               super(BaseVisibilizer, self).__init__()
```

---

This is the base class for my User and UserGroup classes: both classes
can be used to control the visibility of certain items.

```
class UserGroup(BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer):
       __tablename__ = "user_groups"
       _id = Column("id", Integer, ForeignKey(BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer.id), primary_key=True)

       __mapper_args__ = {
               'polymorphic_identity': 'UserGroup',
               'inherit_condition': _id == BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer._id,
       }

       _name = Column("name", String(50), nullable=False)
```

---

```
class User(BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer):
       __tablename__ = "users"
       _id = Column("id", Integer, ForeignKey(BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer.id), primary_key=True)

       __mapper_args__ = {
               'polymorphic_identity': 'User',
               'inherit_condition': _id == BaseVisibilizer.BaseVisibilizer._id,
       }
       _firstName = Column("first_name", String(50), key="fistName")
       _lastName = Column("last_name", String(50), key="lastName")
       _userName = Column("user_name", String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

---

In many of the other classes of my system I have a relationship that
can contain "BaseVisibilizers" (Users or UserGroups).

```
class Whatever(declarativeBase):
       allowedVisibilizers = relationship("BaseVisibilizer",
               secondary="intermediate_whatevers_to_base_visibilizers",
               collection_class=set)
```

---

So in the instances of Whatever, the *allowedVisibilizers* set can
contain instances of User of UserGroup (because both are
BaseVisibilizers). If the logged user or the UserGroup the logged user
belongs to is among the "allowedVisibilizers" , that user will be able
to access (or "see") that instance of Whatever.

At a certain point, I would like to create a method in the Whatever
class that would give me only the allowed visibilizers that are
actually a UserGroup (discarding the Users) but I haven't been able to
do it.

I've tried several things, but obviously, not the right one
(subqueries, joins of "allowedvisibilizers"...):

```
What I'd like is something like:
class Whatever(declarativeBase):
       [ . . . ]
       def getAllowedUserGroups(self):
               session = Database.Session()
               query = session.query(UserGroup.UserGroup).filter(UserGroup.UserGroup.in_(self.allowedVisibilizers))
               return query.all()
```

(but obviously, UserGroup is a class and doesn't have an in_)

Of course, I could always get all the "allowedVisibilizers" and remove
the Users from the returned value, but I was trying to make it a
little bit optimized than that and avoid unnecessary calls to the
database.

Any hint will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create another relationship on `Whatever` which would include the filter to the specific table `UserGroup`, which should do the trick.
See [Multiple Relationships against the Same Parent/Child](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/07/orm/relationships.html#multiple-relationships-against-the-same-parent-child) documentation for more information. In your case adding additional join condition on `UserGroup` table should do the trick.
Also consider using [Building Query-Enabled Properties](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/07/orm/relationships.html#building-query-enabled-properties) to specify `readonly`.